# Django keeps using the wrong project settings file

Tags: python, django

Django keeps trying to use the settings file of a previously deleted project (project-x) when I run `python3 manage.py runserver` for any newly created project resulting in the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'project-x'` when the settings module is initiating. The files/settings in my new project does not reference project-x at all so i'm not sure why this is happening... The error also occurs across different virtual environments.

When I manually set the settings module to that of my new project using the environment variable used by Django `export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=newproject.settings` everything works fine however I would like to find the root problem and fix it. The problem started occurring after I reinstalled python and Django.

Error

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 170, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.1_6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 972, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 984, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'project-x'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you inspect manage.py, you might see that it tries to get the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` from the environment but if it fails, manage.py has a default path to the settings. If you change that you should be able to use the manage.py without setting the environment variable.

Comment: My manage.py already sets a default with ```os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'newproject.settings')``` however for some reason it is being ignored unless I set it before using runserver command..

Comment: Did you set the environment variable before for the old project? You can check it by writing `env` on linux bash or `SET` on windows command prompt.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/58814/how-do-i-add-environment-variables check out this to set your environment variable to the correct value.

Comment: I have never set the environment  before and everything worked. This problem started after I reinstalled python and Django.